# $.getJSON not working when using getSongBPM

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

New to this, please excuse my ignorance.
I would like to get the bpm of a song from getsongbpm public api. There is no data being outputted to the console.

// api key has been changed

```
$.getJSON("https://api.getsongbpm.com/song/api_key=f9af182c18730&id=983pB", function(data){

  console.log(data);

  var tempo =  data.song.tempo;
  console.log(tempo);

 $(".bpm").append(tempo);
});
```

I expect the console to have the output of the data in JSON format.  I used this video for reference.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=InoAIgBZIEA

Comment: After /song/ the title of song should be inserted to find the song and retrieve the data for.

Comment: The link works fine and returns {"song":{"id":"983pB","title":"Highway to Hell","uri":"https:\/\/getsongbpm.com\/song\/highway-to-hell\/983pB","artist":{"id":"qB3","name":"AC\/DC","uri":"https:\/\/getsongbpm.com\/artist\/ac-dc\/qB3","img":"https:\/\/lastfm-img2.akamaized.net\/i\/u\/d3f4e279a056464eb794710d8b4b69b7.png","genres":["heavy metal","rock"],"from":"AU","mbid":"66c662b6-6e2f-4930-8610-912e24c63ed1"},"tempo":"112","time_sig":"4\/4","key_of":"F\u266fm","open_key":"4m"}}

Comment: This is what I got after testing: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.getsongbpm.com/song/api_key=f9af182c18730&id=983pB' from origin 'https://cdpn.io' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: You have to fix that header problem with CORS or for testing you can install 'Moesif CORS' chrome plugin. And it works.

Comment: Thank you @MasoodAslami

Comment: No probI'm @nicholasvar! If you think my last comment helped you, so please upvote my comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to fix that header problem with 'Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS)' or for testing only you can install 'Moesif CORS' chrome plugin and it works.